# TSql Lookup function

Tags: t-sql

I have a bunch of dimension tables that have unique ID and Name fields.  I need a T-SQL function that returns an ID when passed a table name and a value for the name field.

I'm guessing the function would build a little query then execute it? Performance isn't an issue since this is a one time ETL thing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a scalar [user defined function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)
There's a lot of other ways to do it though, and udf's certainly can have some perfomance issues.